# Adding fields to a form and a model dynamically in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Lets say we have a model called SimpleModel and it has an attr connected_field which is ForeignKey of NotSimpleModel
i.e.

```
class SimpleModel(models.Model):
    connected_field = models.ForeignKey('NotSimpleModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='connected')


class NotSimpleModel(models.Model):
    ...
```

and we have a form called NotSimpleForm

```
class NotSimpleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...

    class Meta:
        model = NotSimpleModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Well, actually i wanna do a page form where user can dynamically add "connected_field" (not only this one field. Also fields from NotSimpleModel) to the form which is ModelForm of NotSimpleModel, then all the fields, which user added dynamically should be sent to the view and saved to the db (i doesnt insist on ForeignKey, but i guess it gotta be the easiest way to solve it tho)